# "There's a minimum of three zones within a single region" YET "Not every region has support for availability zones.". How?

Tags: azure, region, availability-zone

This is very basic / fundamental oriented question.

Fact: "There's a minimum of three zones within a single region"
Fact: "Not every region has support for availability zones."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/azure-architecture-fundamentals/regions-availability-zones

How can a region that has no support for availability zones have a minimum of 3 zone?
It doesn't make any logical sense so I guess I am misreading here. So can someone clarify exactly what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confusing a region and an **availability zone-enabled region**. A region can have a single zone. Regions with three or more zones are an **availability zone-enabled region**.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! Very appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 0):

From the official doc:

> Azure availability zones are physically separate locations within each
> Azure region that are tolerant to local failures.

[image]

*`How can a region that has no support for availability zones have a minimum of 3 zone?`*

Not all regions support availability zone at this moment. You can find a list of regions that support availability zones in here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/availability-zones/az-overview#azure-regions-with-availability-zones